# Elastic Beanstalk App in Private VPC without NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to deploy an EB app in a custom private VPC, without using a NAT Gateway? I want to use AWS API Gateway as the public entry point for the app while keeping the services private. After setting everything up, my environment keeps failing with:

```
The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a failed EC2 instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching the environment again.
```

The VPC consists of:

- Two private subnets for the EC2 instances
- Two private subnets for the load balancer

The template I used is [vpc-private.yaml](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/cfn-templates/vpc-private.yaml) from the EB samples repo.

The EB app is a multi-container docker application with a Nginx reverse proxy and a Flask app running with uWSGI (similar to [this configuration](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-deploy-docker-containers-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)). I'm using an **internal** Network Load Balancer and the instances are **not** assigned public IP addresses. The Docker images are hosted in AWS ECR.

A common answer in forums seems to be to have one public subnet with NAT to allow internet access. AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html#services-vpc-private-beanstalk) indicates that using a private/private configuration is possible though by using [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc-vpce.html), as long as the app does not require an internet connection.

The endpoints I have configured are:

```
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs-telemetry
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs-agent
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecs
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.dkr
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ecr.api
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk-health
```

It looks like VPC endpoints for Beanstalk are fairly new and I could not find any other resource explaining how to do this...

Thanks!

## EDIT (solved)

A few setup details I forgot to mention:

- DNS resolution and DNS hostnames are enabled in the VPC
- Private DNS is enabled for every endpoint
- Made sure that the endpoint's security group allowed the instance's VPC as inbound traffic

Thanks to @Marcin suggestion, I was able to log into the instances via Session Manager (just add **ssm**, **ec2messages** and **ssmmessages** endpoints). After checking the logs, I noticed the following error:

```
2020-08-01 15:15:56,801 [WARNING] Timeout of 60 seconds breached
2020-08-01 15:15:56,801 [ERROR] Client-side timeout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 162, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 231, in _timeout
    raise TimeoutError("Execution did not succeed after %s seconds" % duration)
TimeoutError
```

I found [other people](https://linuxandevops.wordpress.com/2017/06/24/aws-cfn-signal-not-working/) had the same issue, and it was caused by *cfn-signal* failing to execute. I was able to solve this by adding the **cloudformation** endpoint. On the following deployment I now noticed a new `sqs connection error` which was solved by adding the **sqs** endpoint.

After adding the mentioned endpoints to the VPC, the deployment succeeded. Either way, I'm not sure why these endpoints were necessary, and why it was not mentioned in the AWS documentation in the first place.

Comment: Also make sure the s3 endpoint is of type "Gateway" and not "Interface" otherwise the s3 curl request from the cfn script will continue to timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template you [linked](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/cfn-templates/vpc-private.yaml) **does not have NAT**, even though the description says it has. AWS mistake.

The template creates **two private** subnets, fully cut off from the internet and any other services, such as EB or ECR.

The important thing to note, and the template fails to showcase it, is to enable [private DNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html#vpce-private-dns) for your endpoints.

For that to work you must ensure that [EnableDnsHostnames](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html#cfn-aws-ec2-vpc-EnableDnsHostnames) and [EnableDnsSupport](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html#cfn-aws-ec2-vpc-EnableDnsHostnames) are **enabled** for the VPC. The template from the docs does not enable them.

These could possibly explain why your VPC interface endpoints don't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, the template description is misleading. I forgot to mention that I did enable both DNS resolution and DNS hostnames in the VPC after creation, as well as private DNS for every endpoint. Any other idea on what could be setup wrong? Or maybe some way of debugging this? Thanks!

Comment: @SemyLevy What about security groups for the VPC interface endpoints? Have you adjusted them? They should allow inbound traffic from the SG of your EB instances.

Comment: I've been using the default security group for both the EB instances and the VPC endpoints. I also tried adding the EB-created security group as an inbound rule to the default right after creation but got the same results :(

Comment: What frustrates me is that I can't get any additional logs except the communication error from EB, so it's hard to tell where it's failing.

Comment: @SemyLevy You would need to create a public subnet, spinup a bastion host, and inspect from there. From bastion host, login to EB instances and check logs. Alternative is to use ssm manager. For that you need to modify EB instance role and add further VPC interface endpoints (for SSM) into the VPC.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was able to solve it by looking at the logs (see edit).

Comment: @SemyLevy Glad it worked out. Its funny though that AWS docs on EB don't even mention the need for CFN endpoint :-(